# Printing stdin text in C

Tags: c, stdin

I understand that by using a random file as stdin, I can print out the first line in the file using the code below.  However, I do not know how to print the remaining lines in stdin.  I think I should use a loop, but I do not know what to put in the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char line[1000];

    fgets(line, 1000, stdin);
    puts(line);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: its supposed to say #include <stdio.h> btw

Comment: e.g `while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
        fputs(line, stdout);`

Answer (score 1):

you should use while loop

```
while(fgets(line, 1000, stdin)!= NULL){
    puts(line);
}
```

Comment: you can use  just    `while(fgets(line, 1000, stdin)){ puts(line);}`

Answer (score 0):

```
while (NULL != fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin))
{
  ...
}
```

will do the trick.  `fgets` returns `NULL` when it reaches end of file (EOF).  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html for more details.